# CartoDB map does not react to tap on Chrome Android

Tags: carto, android, chrome

I [Created a map with CartoDB](http://cdb.io/Zfr2aI)

When you click the polygon, an info window should appear.
It works fine on desktop browsers, it also works fine on my phone with Firefox.
It doesn't seem to work on my phone's Chrome.

Any ideas?

My phone is Nexus 4, Android version 4.4.4
Chrome version 37.0.2062.117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after updating chrome to version 38.0.2125.102
tap seems to be working, I would guess it was a chrome glitch.